# How to use hasNext for this code?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Okay so the problem is to write a program that will identify vowels from consonant. I need to use Scanner and hasNext()

the output should look like this

Enter a letter: a

a is vowel

Enter a letter: b

b is consonant

Enter a letter: 1

1 is invalid input

It will keep reading until it reaches the end of file
professor hinted to use `hasNext`  because it will return false when there is no input

So here is what i have so far

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
    char letter = input.next().charAt(0);

        if (letter=='a'||letter=='A'||letter=='e'||letter=='E'||letter=='i'||letter=='I'||letter=='o'||letter=='O'||letter=='u'||letter=='U'){
            System.out.println(letter + " is a vowel");
        }
        else if(Character.isLetter(letter)){
            System.out.println(letter + " is a consonant");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println(letter + " is an invalid input");

        }
```

What i need is to loop it to after entering any input it would ask it again to enter a letter. And continue looping it until it reaches the end of file with the use of has Next

Comment: Do you want a file or system input?

Comment: In English, y, r, l are sometimes vowels. More importantly, you are counting all non-English letters and all accented letters as consonants. Identification of vowels and consonants for a language in a script is linguistics, and is not well-supported in software libraries. If you write this kind of logic, be sure to include the "don't know" cases rather than produce erroneous results due to unstated assumptions. I think that's the only case where you can make use of Character.isLetter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you heard or understood the hint. You should just use `hasNext()`, which will determine if there is input (of any kind) left. The logic for determining whether the character is a vowel or consonant or invalid is good. You need a while loop that uses `hasNext()` to determine when the end-of-file is reached.

Comment: i'm still a beginner at java, now i understood thanks for your help

Comment: If this answer was helpful, select it as accepted to show that you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char letter;
    System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
    while(input.hasNext())
    {

       letter = input.next().charAt(0);

        if (letter=='a'||letter=='A'||letter=='e'||letter=='E'||letter=='i'||letter=='I'||letter=='o'||letter=='O'||letter=='u'||letter=='U')
        {
            System.out.println(letter + " is a vowel");
        }
        else if(Character.isLetter(letter)){
            System.out.println(letter + " is a consonant");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println(letter + " is an invalid input");

        }

       System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much! i was thinking of inserting the second system.out on each of the condition but i also thought that it is awkward.

Comment: I am a beginner too and i think at the beginning nothing is awkward. Happy codding

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few things you need to do.

1. Read a file. So instead of `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);`, you can use the Scanner object to instead read a file, like this:

   ```
   Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("path\\to\\vowels.txt"));
   ```
2. Loop over that file to test every input. So use a `while` loop.
3. In that loop, there comes the condition of when to stop. Well the [`hasNext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()) will return `true` as long as there is more input in the file, so the condition would be `while (input.hasNext())`. That's how you use the `hasNext()` method to continue reading the file while there is input left.

Don't forget, when reading a file, you have to surround it in a try-catch block just in case the file is not found or something else. You code could look like this:

```
try {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Mike\\Desktop\\vowels.txt"));

    while (input.hasNext()) {
        char letter = input.next().charAt(0);

        if (letter=='a'||letter=='A'||letter=='e'||letter=='E'||letter=='i'||letter=='I'||letter=='o'||letter=='O'||letter=='u'||letter=='U'){
            System.out.println(letter + " is a vowel");
        }
        else if(Character.isLetter(letter)){
            System.out.println(letter + " is a consonant");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(letter + " is an invalid input");
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```